# how to disable input selection notification android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method, custom-keyboard

I have created a custom softKeyboard and I want all application in the devices use this keyboard only. I have added a password restriction to access input Selection setting page. The problem is the notification appears when there are multiple softkeyboards available. Is there any way I can disable this input selection notification or to restrict user to choose the other keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to share my own question's ans so it can help others who are facing same issue.
I have added a custom view on widow at the top so that the status bar to avoid touch event. below is my code.

```
public class ClearStatusBar extends Service {

    private WindowManager mWindowManager;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private static View statusbar;



 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

}


 private WindowManager.LayoutParams getWindowManagerParams() {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR ,
             // Keeps the button presses from going to the background window
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                // Enables the notification to recieve touch events
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                // Draws over status bar
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT); // must be translucent to support KitKat gradient
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        params.x=0;
        int statusBarHeight = getStatusBarHeight();
        params.height = (statusBarHeight>25?statusBarHeight:25);
        return params;
    }

 public int getStatusBarHeight() {
      int result = 0;
      int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
      if (resourceId > 0) {
          result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
      }
      return result;
}



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(statusbar == null){
        statusbar = new View(this);
        statusbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#20000000"));
        mWindowManager.addView(statusbar, getWindowManagerParams());
        if(statusbar != null){
            statusbar.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if(statusbar != null){
        mWindowManager.removeView(statusbar);
        statusbar = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();

}

}
```